# CSS Background-Image issue with safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, safari

I have seen these questions dotted around the web with little response.

I add some CSS in jQuery like:

```
$('#object').css('background-image', 'url(../../Content/Images/green-tick.png');
```

It works in all browsers expect from Safari.

Anyone know as of why? Most answers I have seen to this question say to actually use

> 'background-image'

*(This answers or 'guides' are mostly not on stackoverflow)*

I cant debug the browser as I am only testing this with an iPad.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: could you put up a minimal snippet.

Comment: have you seen accepted answer from this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341728/background-image-not-showing-in-safari

Comment: unable to replicate the error. try to change the particular png to another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the height that you have allocated.
I had a scenario with height: 100%.  That didn't work in Safari.  It wanted the height applied in pixels else the height got set to 0 and hence the image appeared not to be shown (although it was there.  It just had a height of zero)