# Why are the background images not showing on iphones and ipads?

Tags: ios, css, mobile, background-image

I have been trying to troubleshoot this page for what feels like eons.  theafropick.co.uk is the site.  Everything seems to work fine on all devices except on ipads and iphones the section with 6 tiles is completely gone.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please [create an example that duplicates the problem](/help/mcve) and put that code in your question itself? This will make it easier for people to see what's going on and answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's just Safari that is having the issue. Here's a thread that shows other people having the issue:
[Background image not showing in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341728/background-image-not-showing-in-safari)

That thread has many different solutions, and I tried many within the inline safari dev tools without any luck. If they don't work for you either I would try using jpg instead of png.