# Background image not working with Safari browser from my phone

Tags: html, css, safari

I upload my simple website, but when I checked from my phone with the safari browser, I can't see the background image on the top, I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52520637/safari-background-image-not-showing) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341728/background-image-not-showing-in-safari) but both didn't work.

```css
  .header {
    padding: 10%;
    text-align: center;
    background: url("4.jpg"); 
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    
    height: 82vh;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 2em;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-flow: column;
    gap: 1em;

    
  }
```

```html
<header class="header">
        <h1>name surname</h1>
        <p>Front End Web Developer</p>
        <div class="arrow"><a href="#row"></a></div>
    </header>
```

Here is the [My website](http://www.latecoder.com).
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Background Attachments have been disabled in mobile browsers.

Change `background-attachment` to something like `background-size: cover`.

For more information:

[How to replicate background-attachment fixed on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23236158/how-to-replicate-background-attachment-fixed-on-ios)

From the post:

Check [this comment by @PaulIrish:](https://twitter.com/paul_irish/status/306818591196602368)

> Fixed-backgrounds have huge repaint cost and decimate scrolling
> performance, which is, I believe, why it was disabled.

Comment: https://codepen.io/ddk2231/pen/oNevZNw

I changed background-attachment to background-size and it works in mobile.