# Background image in Safari

Tags: css, safari, background-image

I can view the image with every other browser except Safari (version 5.1-8).

Image isn't progressive.

Any idea why this may not show up in Safari?

Comment: You can refer this answer for possible resolution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341728/background-image-not-showing-in-safari

Comment: Hi! I can see the image appears on safari too.

Comment: @AKNair I saw this topic. I didn't find a solution there.

Comment: @EliyaCohen In which version Safari?