# CSS Content property does not work on safari

Tags: css

I have and element and on hover it has an arrow appearing. 
The problem is that it works on chrome and firefox but does not work on safari 12. It works on safari 10 though.

So far I found out that the problem is `content:url('../path/to/arrow.png')` 
If I replace path to the arrow with `content: '1234'` then it works for some reason.
here is a full code

```
<style>
.textwidget a {
    border-radius: 0;
    background-color: none;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 200px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 101px;
    margin-bottom: 94px;
    margin-left: -10px;

}

.textwidget a {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.textwidget a:after {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free" !important;
    content: url(../public/assets/images/icons/arrow-right-small-white.png) !important;
    font-weight: 600 !important;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    top: 3px;
    right: 23px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.textwidget a:hover{
    padding-right: 24px;
    padding-left:3px;
}

.textwidget a:hover:after {
    opacity: 1;
    right: 10px;
}

</style>

<div class="textwidget">
   <p>
      <a href="#">Link</a>
   </p>
</div>
```

So my desired output is that `content: url(../public/assets/images/icons/arrow-right-small-white.png)`

works also on safari 12

Comment: Looks similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341728/background-image-not-showing-in-safari

Comment: @MahendraPratap Thanks for the input but I tried all of them and still does not work

Answer (score -1):

Try mount the arrow on span element instead and do it like in [docs](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/advanced/css-pseudo-elements), so without content property