# CSS background-image don't work on Safari browser

Tags: html, css, safari, background-image, mobile-safari

My images don't work on Safari browser (iPhone 6,7,8...), it works on Chrome, Opera, Firefox. 
Please help me. 
Here is my live project http://plocastinamestajleske.com/

**CSS code**

```
.logo {
  background-image: url("/assets/img/logo.png");
  background-image: url("/assets/img/logo.webp");
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a similar problem and converting my image from png to gif helped. There are a few known bugs with Safari and background images.

[This link to a similar problem might have some other solutions if mine doesn't work.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341728/background-image-not-showing-in-safari)

Comment: I changed images to gif, also remove webp format, put some heights on parent and now it work. Thank you