# Safari returns missing image after jump link [HTML/CSS]

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

I have a page, let's say its myweb.com/about-us. It has various sections which are accessible from my navigation bar by using a jump link, i.e. click at myweb.com/about-us/#team and it goes to the #team section.

Problems arise when I open the website with Safari. At myweb.com/about-us, everything is working as they are. However, when I use the link myweb.com/about-us/#team, most images on the page loads, but some images just disappears. Even my logo that is on the navigation bar.

My navigation bar:

```
<img src="myweb.com/assets/img/missinglogo.png"> <a href="myweb.com/about-us/#team>The Team</a>
```

And the page:

```
<html>
<body> 
<section id="other">
Other contents here.
<img src="myweb.com/assets/img/anothermissingimage.png">
</section>
<section id="team">List of team members here</section>
</body>
</html>
```

It's straight forward and is working on any other browsers, so what could be the problem here with Safari?

My image src are dynamic. It calls images by myweb.com/assets/img/img.png so I can't wrap my head around how Safari cannot find it? The images that do load are using the same image src.

The similarities between the images that are missing are that they are small. They don't go over 200px.

Only references I could find with a close relation are something like these:
[Background image not showing in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341728/background-image-not-showing-in-safari)

- Which doesn't work for me because, first, it's not a background.
- My images are not progressive encoded
- I have resized the images and the error still persists
- None of the missing images have z-index properties
- I have changed the image type from PNG to GIF, and the problem is still there.

Comment: What happens when you add http:// or https:// in front of the url?

Comment: I'm at https. The website is designed so that when you open the http version, it redirects itself to the https version. Should I try forcing it to stay on http anyway just to see?

Comment: I just tried with http. Problem's still there

Comment: what happens if you change `<img src="myweb.com/assets/img/missinglogo.png">` for `<img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/missinglogo.png'); ?>">` ?

Comment: Just tried it. Same problem

Comment: Might sound weird, but could you try giving the image height of 100%?

Comment: Just tried it. The image appeared for a split second while the page is loading, but when it finished loading the image returned the same error. I tried saving the image into the device, it's not downloading. But when I'm on the myweb.com/about-us, the image is loading and I can download it into the device.

Comment: Test with other Safari - it may be a device problem - clean up cookies, cache etc; check page on https://validator.w3.org/unicorn/; test with relative path `<img src="../../img/anothermissingimage.png">`; image appears and disappears - last time I  experienced with dying connection and huge images...

Comment: Hi, I validated with the tool you linked and it didn't pass the HTML check, but it didn't specify anything about my disappearing images (error were on the other parts of the page). What exactly should I be looking for, in relation to said images?

Comment: I have also tried a relative path, cleared cache, and tried Safari on a new device. Same problem.